# How to edit the content page fields column in the admin section?

Tags: 7

In the admin section --> Content menu displays all the contents of the site.

[image]

I want to have options (or atleast to know where I have to change) for adding and removing the columns in the content section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the easiest way is to install the [admin views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) module (and its dependencies).

That module will replace Drupal core's implementation of that listing (and the taxonomy, comment, user and book listings) with a views based one.
You can then edit the 'Administration: Nodes' view and change the columns ('Fields' in the Views UI) as you see fit.

Alternatively, you could create own custom view that uses the admin/content path, to override the core listing. That would have the same effect but would be a little extra effort in setting up the view.

Comment: This is the solution, which is suggested to me from my colleagues. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x) and do your changes inside that.

Example:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_form_node_admin_content_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 // YOUR CUSTOM CODE GOES HERE
}
```

Comment: Thanks I am new to drupal 7, I try it and update my comments.